# KiCad leave room for optional through hole resistor on top of default SMD?

Tags: pcb, resistors, surface-mount, kicad, through-hole

I was wondering how one would go about creating a footprint for an SMD resistor leaving room for a through hole one to be soldered on top should one wish to adjust the value, a bit as seen on this PCB by Adafruit:

https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/18726

Comment: Do you know how to create/modify a footprint in KiCad?

Comment: I have done that before, but it would be helpful if you could help me in making sure the connection works with both the optional resistor plugged in and without

Comment: Assuming you update both the schematic symbol and the footprint you can verify that everything is wired just like any other part.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will give that a go!

Comment: Maybe you just put both parts in the schematic and overlay the footprints on the PCB. You may get a DRC error as a result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to create a new footprint with duplicated pads, the easiest way is probably to put two resistors in parallel in your schematics. Assign one SMD and one THT footprint.

[image: Resistors in schematics]

Then, stack the two footprints on top of each other.

[image: Resistors in PCB editor]

Comment: This is the way, then you can have both lines in your BOM and mark one as not fitted.